# socket.io callback function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, callback

I used to use socket.io emit callback like following:

client:

```
mysocket.emit('helloword', 'helloword', function(param){
        console.log(param);
    });
```

server:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var sserver = io(server);
sserver.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection');
    socket.on('helloword', function(message, callback){
        console.log(message);
        console.log(callback+'');
        console.log('arguments', arguments);
        callback('helloword');
    })
});
server.listen(config.port);
```

I'm using [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) as a wrapper for socket.io-client. My service is simple as:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').factory('mysocket', function(socketFactory){
    return socketFactory();
});
```

server output:

```
connection
helloword
function (){
    // prevent double callbacks
    if (sent) return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    debug('sending ack %j', args);

    var type = hasBin(args) ? parser.BINARY_ACK : parser.ACK;
    self.packet({
      id: id,
      type: type,
      data: args
    });
  }
arguments { '0': 'helloword', '1': [Function] }
```

My client console:

My question:

- Why my callback is not firing ?

Answer (score 1):

The function `socket.on(event, callback)` will listen for an event from the client and then run the callback when the event is triggered. In your case, when it hears 'helloword' it will run the callback function that you defined as the second parameter: `function(message, callback)`. Your server log output shows that, actually, all of the `console.log` calls in your callback are being run.

Comment: Im not talking about the callback running in the server. Is about the callback running on client fired from the server

Comment: The console.log in my client is not firing

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on client side try set the localStorage.debug = '*'
See this for more info: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#log-differences (assuming you use socketio 1.0+)